# Double minus inc css calc?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I've found in Semantic UI CSS file (semantic.css) double minus! 
You can download full file here: 
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.css

What does it mean?
Here is example:
`width: calc(100% + (--1px * 2));`

Here is the whole style:

```
 .ui.attached.steps {
   width: calc(100% + (--1px * 2)) !important;
   margin: 0em -1px 0;
   max-width: calc(100% + (--1px * 2));
   border-radius: 0.28571429rem 0.28571429rem 0em 0em;
 }
```

Comment: according to the rules (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-syntax) this is simply invalid

Comment: It means nothing, the only `--` semantic I know is for variables, like `height: var(--height);`. Where did you find it anyway?

Comment: That what it does:https://i.stack.imgur.com/iijIv.png

Comment: @HaoWu https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/deb275d2d5fe9a522a0b7bd8b6b6a1c939552718/dist/components/step.css#L494

Comment: And it doesn't make it through the W3C CSS validator. So, that answers your question then.

Comment: But judging by the mixing units of `em`, `rem`, `px`, `%` and `0`, `margin` with 3 attributes, ridiculous fractal digits, use of `!important` and massive class chain, it may not be the best example to learn from... Must be some compiled css with errors.

Comment: The change came with 2.4.1. It was simply `calc(100% + 2px)` before... [Diff of the versions 2.4.0 - 2.4.1](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/commit/e7d04788fb5ba3314e289759f5b27b51fe6eed6d#diff-d7935b6ba2b3af0ffcf4ca6c0b0d9357R494)